# I can't change bank preset in my keyboard via Ableton

Tags: midi, keyboard, ableton-live

I own Casio CT-X5000 keyboard and tried to use its appendix with bank and program changes to reach tones I'd want. What I wanted to do is send midi out from Ableton to my keyboard with appropriate bank and program change, so my keyboard then can produce the sound I desire and send it back to my audio interface (and the Ableton) to record it. So it's a pretty usual setup.

The problem is, no matter which bank program I choose, the only thing that is being sent are GM (general midi) signals causing my keyboard to play only the sounds from general midi (there are 128 of them).

Here's the appendix:
https://support.casio.com/storage/en/manual/pdf/EN/008/Web_14M3APPEND-WL-1A_2A_EN.pdf

I'm using columns 4 (program change) and 5 (bank select) and put them accordingly in "midi bank select" and "midi program change" brackets on my Midi track.

Have any of you had this kind of an issue? I'd really appreciate if you knew something that could help me in this situation. I've been struggling for a long time with it and have no idea why my keyboard does not receive these messages (to change bank and program) and still plays general midi.

=============================SOLUTION==============================

I've finally figured it out. It works both on Ableton and FL studio, but the difference is that Ableton counts from 1 both in Bank and Program change, but in FL studio in midi out plugin it is counting from 1 for Program change and from 0 for Bank change. So there' the confusion, because you have to take into account how your hardware counts these.

In FL studio sometimes you have to hit "stop" and "play" button to have program change sent to the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like this: https://imgur.com/Me46g8k
  That's for Nylon Guitar Velo.Slide, first in guitar section. In this case my keyboard would just play 32 sound from GM, and that is "guitar harmonics" or something like that. It's like it does not send the bank change.

Comment: I don't know the app, so I don't know how it sends. tbh, for something as simple as a bank/prog change I'd just enter the data manually at the top of the track, then you know it's right. Or, if the keyboard sends it, record it & see what it looks like.

Comment: I'd love to manually enter the data, but how? I'm new to Ableton. Keyboard sends midi and it works just fine. Only receiving does not seem to work right.

Comment: It's possible that bank select messages are ignored in GM mode; tell Ableton to not send a "GM System On" message; or manually send a "GM System Off" message.

Comment: Sorry - that falls right into the realm of 'read the manual'.

Comment: Can you create a very short MIDI file (with one note) in Ableton, and show it here?

Comment: I'll try to disable sending GM data. By show you mean post a screenshot? Or is there a way of sending files on music.stackexchange?

Comment: You could edit the question and say that the General MIDI thing was just an incorrect assumption. I don't think there's any special General MIDI stuff happening, it may just seem that way until you get the numbers exactly right. Even if you get the bank and program numbers _almost_ right, it doesn't seem to make sense... the sound may change, or maybe it doesn't change at all, and you're like "is this working at all or not". Both numbers have to be _exactly_ right, with the 0-based and 1-based numbers translated correctly, and then you get the right sounds and suddenly it makes sense.

Comment: Yep, that's right, although in FL studio there's some weird stuff happening. Sometimes the bank change won't change unless you hit "stop" followed by "play" to kinda reset the whole thing, or it will start playing General Midi when you change bank/program.

Comment: Did you find a way to check from the CT-X5000's front panel, what sound is selected on what part? The display screen does not seem to show that the patches are changing. Overall, the whole user interface is a big mess, much more confusing than any Casio I've seen. All functions and menus have a different way of working and navigating, and it's easy to end up in a state where you don't know where you are and how to get out. There's no consistent safe "exit" button and it's impossible to know what button to press and _how_. "Long press" of some random button. Awful! Cannot recommend for anyone.

Comment: Yes I was choosing sounds in DAW and it played them through casio and to be sure I checked it by manually changing to the same sound in keyboard and playing it, so I was sure this is it. Is this what you wanted to know? Yeah the display itself does not show changes that came with midi from DAW, so it's a bit of a hit or miss. You have to know what you're going for. You can have piano selected on keybaord buy the horn will play (if you chose horn on midi out in DAW). Hah yeah it's easy to get lost in menus here, but how could I know. It's my first keyboard.

Comment: "You have to know what you're going for." Exactly! ;) The command and button press sequences have to be exactly right, and you just have to know everything precisely, _ignoring_ the confusing signals (or lack thereof) given by the user-facing parts of the device. All people who understood human communication must have been retired or fired from the company or something. I bought the keyboard for my kids, but it's way too difficult to use any but the most basic features. Making your own rhythms, sounds, recording ... forget it. Even with the manual it's nearly impossible to use, as you've seen.

Comment: Haha yeah maybe that's what happened there, but to be honest maybe that's how it looks (messy) because they wanted to put too much in the keyboard and the screen is too small to comfortable show everything? I don't know. Maybe if I buy another one in future I'll find out. To be honest I thought it just has to be that way, I had no previous experience with keyboard's UI's so I assumed it's just as it is supposed to be. But yeah I can totally imagine kids' confusion when it comes to recording something here. I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but do you have exactly same keyboard? TBC

Comment: As me, that means CT-X5000? I'm lucky then, because no one in the entire internet (well maybe except one person in casio forum) could help me with my issue. Damn manufacturers. I'm happy I'm over it finally! What a relief after a week of mind boggling search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the bank and program numbers to Ableton's MIDI clip. When Ableton's playback enters the MIDI clip, it sends the appropriate bank-change and program-change messages before sending any of the MIDI notes in the clip.

Use the numbers from Casio's list, plus one. Casio's numbering is 0-based, Ableton's numbering is 1-based. In Casio's numbering, there is no "128", the highest number is 127. In Ableton's numbering, there's no "0", the smallest number is 1.

[image: Casio vs Ableton MIDI patch and bank numbers]

Comment: It worked. You're the man. Thank you very much! :) It works both on Ableton and FL studio, but the difference is that Ableton counts from 1 both in Bank and Program change, but in FL studio in midi out plugin it is counting from 1 for Program change and from 0 for Bank change. I'm so happy it works. Finally...